# My 3d game now only runs on Internet Explorer

Tags: three.js

Years ago I make a 3D game on Construct 2 with 3D plugin "Q3D" (Three.js). It runs well in Chrome and Firefox
Suddenly one day, my game it stopped working.

The URL of the game is http://altiplanet.github.io

Is rare because the game run on Internet Explorer.
I view the console but I do not understand anything (various errors appear)
Very Thanks!

Comment: Please include the errors with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses the `setVelocity()` method of the `PannerNode` class from the Web Audio API.

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PannerNode/setVelocity), this method is deprecated and should no longer be in use.

`PannerNode.setVelocity()` is used in your class `C2AudioInstance` which is no part of the `three.js` API.